# Databricks sql output

Tags: sql, databricks

I have written a query in databricks sql and the output isn't what I am expecting.  Have tried a few methods to determine the cause and am stuck, hoping you can help.

The output is currently producing multiple PeriodStartDate rows per EmployeeID.  Where it should only be a single PeriodStartDate row per EmployeeID.

When I update the query to only run for a single EmployeeID, it works fine.  It is just when I run the query on the full employee list that it is duplicating data.

Image 1 shows the duplication

[image]

Image 2 shows it when run just on EmployeeID 100085, no duplicates.

[image]

It's a long query, apologies, hoping someone can spot what is going on or offer suggestions to de-bug.

```
WITH EmploymentPositionHistory AS (
    SELECT 
        Trim(t104f005_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        Trim(t104f015_occupancy_type) as OccupancyType,
        Trim(t104f020_movement_code) as MovementCode,
        Cast(Trim(t104f025_date_effective) as DATE) as MovementStartDate,
        Cast(Trim(t104f035_connect_date_to) as DATE) as MovementEndDate,
        Trim(t104f040_position_no) as PositionID,
        Trim(t104f050_classification) as Classification,
        Trim(t104f055_increment_point) as PayPoint,
        Trim(t104f085_employment_type) as EmploymentType,
        Trim(t104f095_attendance_type) as AttendanceType,
        Trim(t104f120_comments) as PayrollComments,
        Trim(t104f125_job_code) as JobCode,
        Trim(t001f010_wami_key) as WAMIKey,
        Trim(t001f015_employee_status) as EmploymentStatus,
        CAST(Trim(t001f250_date_commenced) as DATE) as EmployeeIDStartDate,
        CAST(Trim(t001f251_original_date_comm) as DATE) as MaterStartDate,
        CAST(Trim(t001f265_date_terminated) as DATE) as EmployeeIDTerminationDate,
        Trim(t000f030_salutation) as Salutation,
        Concat(Trim(t000f025_preferred_name),' ',INITCAP(Trim(t000f015_surname))) as EmployeeName,
        Trim(t000f025_preferred_name) as PreferredName,
        Trim(t000f020_given_names) as GivenName,
        INITCAP(Trim(t000f015_surname)) as Surname,
        Trim(t000f085_initials) as Initials,
        Trim(t000f110_date_of_birth) as DateOfBirth,
        Trim(t000f105_gender) as Gender,
        Trim(t000f285_postal_postcode) as PostalPostCode,
        Trim(t000f280_postal_state) as PostalState,
        Trim(t000f295_postal_country) as PostalCountry,
        Trim(t000f160_email_address) as PersonalEmail
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t104_employment_history t104
--Join the aurion_t001_basic_details to grab employee specific info
      LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t001_basic_details t001
      ON Trim(t001f005_employee_no) = Trim(t104f005_employee_no)
      AND t001.dh_current_flag = true
      AND t001.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
--Join the aurion_t000_wami to grab employee specific info
      LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t000_wami t000
      ON Trim(t000f005_wami_key) = Trim(t001f010_wami_key)
      AND t000.dh_current_flag = true
      AND t000.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t104f045_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t104.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t104.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
    --AND trim(t104f005_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistoryInitital as 
(   SELECT 
        trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate,
        trim(t050f045_award_code) as AwardCode,
        trim(t050f050_pay_entity) as PayEntity,
        trim(t050f055_pay_branch) as PayBranch,
        CAST(trim(t050f070_contract_expiry_date) as DATE) as ContractExpiryDate,
        trim(t050f075_hours_per_week) as HoursPerWeek,
        if(Trim(t050f215_employment_type) in ('CASUAL','STUDNT','VOL','BOARD') , 0 ,
        (substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,1,2) * 60 * 60
        + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,4,2) * 60
        + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,7,2)) * 1.0 / 3600 ) as ContractedHoursPerWeek,
        if(Trim(t050f215_employment_type) in ('CASUAL','STUDNT','VOL','BOARD')  , 0 ,
       ((substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,1,2) * 60 * 60
       + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,4,2) * 60
       + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,7,2)) * 1.0 / 3600 ) 
       /
       (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t206f050_hours_per_week, ':', 1) AS INT) + 
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t206f050_hours_per_week, ':', -2), ':', 1) AS INT) / 60)) as ContractedFTE,
       trim(t050f180_position_number) as PositionID,
       RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY trim(t050f015_employee_no)
            ORDER BY CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) ASC
        ) AS ContractRank
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule t050
--Join the position table to retrieve the award hours for contracted FTE calculation
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t101_position t101
        ON Trim(t050f180_position_number) = Trim(t101f005_position_no)
        AND t101.dh_current_flag = true
        AND t101.dh_record_deleted_flag = false        
--Join the classification details to retrieve the award hours for contracted FTE calculation
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t206_classification t206 
        ON Trim(t101.t101f020_classification) = Trim(t206.t206f005_classification_code)
        and t206.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t206.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t050f205_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the aurion_t050_change_schedule table back onto itself to identify the when an effective date record was last modified per employee
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmpID
            ,CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate
            ,MAX(Trim(t050f990_modify_date_time))as ModifiedDateTime
        FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule 
        WHERE dh_current_flag = true
        AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
        AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
        AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    --AND Trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100320
    GROUP BY Trim(t050f015_employee_no),CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE)
) t2
--Where statement for main part of the query
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
    AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    AND CAST(t050.t050f030_effective_date as DATE) = t2.EffectiveDate
    AND Trim(t050.t050f990_modify_date_time)  = t2.ModifiedDateTime
    AND t050.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t050.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
    --AND trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistoryToDate as 
(
    SELECT 
        trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) - 1 as EffectiveDateTo,
       RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY trim(t050f015_employee_no)
            ORDER BY CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) ASC
        ) -1 AS PrevContractRank
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule t050
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t050f205_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the aurion_t050_change_schedule table back onto itself to identify the when an effective date record was last modified per employee
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmpID
            ,CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate
            ,MAX(Trim(t050f990_modify_date_time))as ModifiedDateTime
        FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule 
        WHERE dh_current_flag = true
        AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
        AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
        AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    --AND Trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100320
    GROUP BY Trim(t050f015_employee_no),CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE)
) t2
--Where statement for main part of the query
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
    AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    AND CAST(t050.t050f030_effective_date as DATE) = t2.EffectiveDate
    AND Trim(t050.t050f990_modify_date_time)  = t2.ModifiedDateTime
    AND t050.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t050.dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
    --AND trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistory as 
(
    SELECT t1.*,
        CAST(coalesce(t2.EffectiveDateTo,'2099-12-31') as DATE) as EffectiveDateTo
    FROM EmploymentContractHistoryInitital t1
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentContractHistoryToDate t2
    ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
    and t1.ContractRank = t2.PrevContractRank

)

--this is the start of the final output

SELECT 
    CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) AS PeriodStartDate,
    CAST(trim(t916f010_period_end_date) AS DATE) AS PeriodEndDate,
    Trim(t916f018_financial_year) AS FinancialYear,
    Trim(t916f020_pay_no) AS PayNo,
    if(nonsub.OccupancyType is null, sub.OccupancyType, nonsub.OccupancyType) as OccupancyType,
    if(nonsub.OccupancyType is null, sub.MovementCode, nonsub.MovementCode) as MovementCode,
    if(nonsub.EmployeeID is null, sub.EmployeeID, nonsub.EmployeeID) as EmployeeID,
    if(nonsub.EmploymentType is null, sub.EmploymentType, nonsub.EmploymentType) as EmploymentType,
    if(nonsub.AttendanceType is null, sub.AttendanceType, nonsub.AttendanceType) as AttendanceType,
    if(nonsub.PositionID is null, sub.PositionID, nonsub.PositionID) as PositionID,
    if(nonsub.Classification is null, sub.Classification, nonsub.Classification) as Classification,
    if(nonsub.PayPoint is null, sub.PayPoint, nonsub.PayPoint) as PayPoint,
    if(nonsub.JobCode is null, sub.JobCode, nonsub.JobCode) as JobCode,
    if(nonsub.MovementStartDate is null, sub.MovementStartDate, nonsub.MovementStartDate) as MovementStartDate,
    if(nonsub.MovementEndDate is null, sub.MovementEndDate, nonsub.MovementEndDate) as MovementEndDate,
    if(nonsub.PayrollComments is null, sub.PayrollComments, nonsub.PayrollComments) as PayrollComments,
    ech.EffectiveDate,
    ech.EffectiveDateTo,
    ech.ContractExpiryDate,
    ech.AwardCode,
    ech.PayEntity,
    ech.PayBranch,
    ech.ContractedHoursPerWeek,
    ech.ContractedFTE,
    ech.ContractRank as ContractNumber
FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t916_pay_period
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentPositionHistory nonsub
    ON nonsub.OccupancyType = 'NONSUBS' 
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN nonsub.MovementStartDate and nonsub.MovementEndDate
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentPositionHistory sub
    ON sub.OccupancyType = 'SUBS' 
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN sub.MovementStartDate and sub.MovementEndDate  
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentContractHistory ech
    ON if(nonsub.EmployeeID is null, sub.EmployeeID, nonsub.EmployeeID) = ech.EmployeeID 
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN ech.EffectiveDate and ech.EffectiveDateTo
WHERE t916f005_pay_cycle_id = 1
AND dh_current_flag = true
AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(t916f018_financial_year, 4, 2) AS INT) >= CAST(SUBSTRING((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 2), 3, 2) as INT)
--AND if(nonsub.EmployeeID is null, sub.EmployeeID, nonsub.EmployeeID) = 50125
```

Comment: You have not used `EmployeeID` in the `LEFT JOIN` in the main query between `aurion_t916_pay_period` and `nonsub` and `sub`

Comment: [mcve], https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: @ORA-01017 mate you are a legend!!!  Thank you so much, that has resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in how I was joining the EmploymentPositionHistory table. Initially it was just joining the table on twice, both based on date ranges, which was causing the individual employee records to duplicate.

The solution was for the second join to also join based on an employee ID match.  `AND sub.EmployeeID = nonsub.EmployeeID`

I also changed the order of the joins to ensure accuracy.

```
/*************************************************************************
Description  : This master query creates a table off the aurion_t916_pay_period table by only loading the dates from P1.  It then joins multiple tables onto it
to create a record per pay period for each employee.  Calculations will then be performed at each different pay period.
            
Design Decisions: 
1.  Only P1 will be used for historical results as the organisation is moving all employees against P1.

Change History        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date finished Who  Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
xx/01/2024    Carl Initial version
             
*************************************************************************/

WITH EmploymentPositionHistory AS (
    SELECT 
        Trim(t104f005_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        Trim(t104f015_occupancy_type) as OccupancyType,
        Trim(t104f020_movement_code) as MovementCode,
        Cast(Trim(t104f025_date_effective) as DATE) as MovementStartDate,
        Cast(Trim(t104f035_connect_date_to) as DATE) as MovementEndDate,
        Trim(t104f040_position_no) as PositionID,
        Trim(t104f050_classification) as Classification,
        Trim(t104f055_increment_point) as PayPoint,
        Trim(t104f085_employment_type) as EmploymentType,
        Trim(t104f095_attendance_type) as AttendanceType,
        Trim(t104f120_comments) as PayrollComments,
        Trim(t104f125_job_code) as JobCode,
        Trim(t001f010_wami_key) as WAMIKey,
        Trim(t001f015_employee_status) as EmploymentStatus,
        CAST(Trim(t001f250_date_commenced) as DATE) as EmployeeIDStartDate,
        CAST(Trim(t001f251_original_date_comm) as DATE) as MaterStartDate,
        CAST(Trim(t001f265_date_terminated) as DATE) as EmployeeIDTerminationDate,
        Trim(t000f030_salutation) as Salutation,
        Concat(Trim(t000f025_preferred_name),' ',INITCAP(Trim(t000f015_surname))) as EmployeeName,
        Trim(t000f025_preferred_name) as PreferredName,
        Trim(t000f020_given_names) as GivenName,
        INITCAP(Trim(t000f015_surname)) as Surname,
        Trim(t000f085_initials) as Initials,
        Trim(t000f110_date_of_birth) as DateOfBirth,
        Trim(t000f105_gender) as Gender,
        Trim(t000f285_postal_postcode) as PostalPostCode,
        Trim(t000f280_postal_state) as PostalState,
        Trim(t000f295_postal_country) as PostalCountry,
        Trim(t000f160_email_address) as PersonalEmail
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t104_employment_history t104
--Join the aurion_t001_basic_details to grab employee specific info
      LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t001_basic_details t001
      ON Trim(t001f005_employee_no) = Trim(t104f005_employee_no)
      AND t001.dh_current_flag = true
      AND t001.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
--Join the aurion_t000_wami to grab employee specific info
      LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t000_wami t000
      ON Trim(t000f005_wami_key) = Trim(t001f010_wami_key)
      AND t000.dh_current_flag = true
      AND t000.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t104f045_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t104.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t104.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
    --AND trim(t104f005_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistoryInitital as 
(   SELECT 
        trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate,
        trim(t050f045_award_code) as AwardCode,
        trim(t050f050_pay_entity) as PayEntity,
        trim(t050f055_pay_branch) as PayBranch,
        CAST(trim(t050f070_contract_expiry_date) as DATE) as ContractExpiryDate,
        trim(t050f075_hours_per_week) as HoursPerWeek,
        if(Trim(t050f215_employment_type) in ('CASUAL','STUDNT','VOL','BOARD') , 0 ,
        (substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,1,2) * 60 * 60
        + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,4,2) * 60
        + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,7,2)) * 1.0 / 3600 ) as ContractedHoursPerWeek,
        if(Trim(t050f215_employment_type) in ('CASUAL','STUDNT','VOL','BOARD')  , 0 ,
       ((substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,1,2) * 60 * 60
       + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,4,2) * 60
       + substring(t050f075_hours_per_week,7,2)) * 1.0 / 3600 ) 
       /
       (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t206f050_hours_per_week, ':', 1) AS INT) + 
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t206f050_hours_per_week, ':', -2), ':', 1) AS INT) / 60)) as ContractedFTE,
       trim(t050f180_position_number) as PositionID,
       RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY trim(t050f015_employee_no)
            ORDER BY CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) ASC
        ) AS ContractRank
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule t050
--Join the position table to retrieve the award hours for contracted FTE calculation
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t101_position t101
        ON Trim(t050f180_position_number) = Trim(t101f005_position_no)
        AND t101.dh_current_flag = true
        AND t101.dh_record_deleted_flag = false        
--Join the classification details to retrieve the award hours for contracted FTE calculation
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t206_classification t206 
        ON Trim(t101.t101f020_classification) = Trim(t206.t206f005_classification_code)
        and t206.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t206.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t050f205_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the aurion_t050_change_schedule table back onto itself to identify the when an effective date record was last modified per employee
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmpID
            ,CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate
            ,MAX(Trim(t050f990_modify_date_time))as ModifiedDateTime
        FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule 
        WHERE dh_current_flag = true
        AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
        AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
        AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    --AND Trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100320
    GROUP BY Trim(t050f015_employee_no),CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE)
) t2
--Where statement for main part of the query
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
    AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    AND CAST(t050.t050f030_effective_date as DATE) = t2.EffectiveDate
    AND Trim(t050.t050f990_modify_date_time)  = t2.ModifiedDateTime
    AND t050.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t050.dh_record_deleted_flag = false
    --AND trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistoryToDate as 
(
    SELECT 
        trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmployeeID,
        CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) - 1 as EffectiveDateTo,
       RANK () OVER ( 
            PARTITION BY trim(t050f015_employee_no)
            ORDER BY CAST(trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) ASC
        ) -1 AS PrevContractRank
    FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule t050
--Join the org unit table to exclude the other entities
        LEFT JOIN data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t106_organisation_units t106 
        ON Trim(t050f205_organisation_unit_no) = Trim(t106f005_organisation_unit_no)
        and t106.dh_current_flag = 'true'
        and t106.dh_record_deleted_flag = 'false'
--Join the aurion_t050_change_schedule table back onto itself to identify the when an effective date record was last modified per employee
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT Trim(t050f015_employee_no) as EmpID
            ,CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE) as EffectiveDate
            ,MAX(Trim(t050f990_modify_date_time))as ModifiedDateTime
        FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t050_change_schedule 
        WHERE dh_current_flag = true
        AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
        AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
        AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    --AND Trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100320
    GROUP BY Trim(t050f015_employee_no),CAST(Trim(t050f030_effective_date) as DATE)
) t2
--Where statement for main part of the query
    WHERE Trim(t106f075_org_unit_level_02) in ('Mater Foundation','Mater Misericordiae Ltd','Mater Research')
    AND t050f075_hours_per_week is not null
    AND (NOT t050f045_award_code LIKE ('%TRAN%') OR t050f045_award_code is null)
    AND CAST(t050.t050f030_effective_date as DATE) = t2.EffectiveDate
    AND Trim(t050.t050f990_modify_date_time)  = t2.ModifiedDateTime
    AND t050.dh_current_flag = true
    AND t050.dh_record_deleted_flag = false 
    --AND trim(t050f015_employee_no) = 100085
),

EmploymentContractHistory as 
(
    SELECT t1.*,
        CAST(coalesce(t2.EffectiveDateTo,'2099-12-31') as DATE) as EffectiveDateTo
    FROM EmploymentContractHistoryInitital t1
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentContractHistoryToDate t2
    ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
    and t1.ContractRank = t2.PrevContractRank

)

--this is the start of the final output

SELECT 
    CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) AS PeriodStartDate,
    CAST(trim(t916f010_period_end_date) AS DATE) AS PeriodEndDate,
    Trim(t916f018_financial_year) AS FinancialYear,
    Trim(t916f020_pay_no) AS PayNo,
    if(nonsub.OccupancyType is null, sub.OccupancyType, nonsub.OccupancyType) as OccupancyType,
    if(nonsub.OccupancyType is null, sub.MovementCode, nonsub.MovementCode) as MovementCode,
    if(nonsub.EmployeeID is null, sub.EmployeeID, nonsub.EmployeeID) as EmployeeID,
    if(nonsub.EmploymentType is null, sub.EmploymentType, nonsub.EmploymentType) as EmploymentType,
    if(nonsub.AttendanceType is null, sub.AttendanceType, nonsub.AttendanceType) as AttendanceType,
    if(nonsub.PositionID is null, sub.PositionID, nonsub.PositionID) as PositionID,
    if(nonsub.Classification is null, sub.Classification, nonsub.Classification) as Classification,
    if(nonsub.PayPoint is null, sub.PayPoint, nonsub.PayPoint) as PayPoint,
    if(nonsub.JobCode is null, sub.JobCode, nonsub.JobCode) as JobCode,
    if(nonsub.MovementStartDate is null, sub.MovementStartDate, nonsub.MovementStartDate) as MovementStartDate,
    if(nonsub.MovementEndDate is null, sub.MovementEndDate, nonsub.MovementEndDate) as MovementEndDate,
    if(nonsub.PayrollComments is null, sub.PayrollComments, nonsub.PayrollComments) as PayrollComments,
    ech.EffectiveDate,
    ech.EffectiveDateTo,
    ech.ContractExpiryDate,
    ech.AwardCode,
    ech.PayEntity,
    ech.PayBranch,
    ech.ContractedHoursPerWeek,
    ech.ContractedFTE,
    ech.ContractRank as ContractNumber
FROM data_hub_prod.data_hub_raw_history.aurion_t916_pay_period
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentPositionHistory sub
    ON sub.OccupancyType = 'SUBS' 
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN sub.MovementStartDate and sub.MovementEndDate  
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentPositionHistory nonsub
    ON nonsub.OccupancyType = 'NONSUBS' 
    AND sub.EmployeeID = nonsub.EmployeeID
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN nonsub.MovementStartDate and nonsub.MovementEndDate
    LEFT JOIN EmploymentContractHistory ech
    ON sub.EmployeeID = ech.EmployeeID 
    AND CAST(trim(t916f015_period_start_date) AS DATE) BETWEEN ech.EffectiveDate and ech.EffectiveDateTo
WHERE t916f005_pay_cycle_id = 1
AND dh_current_flag = true
AND dh_record_deleted_flag = false
AND CAST(SUBSTRING(t916f018_financial_year, 4, 2) AS INT) >= CAST(SUBSTRING((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 2), 3, 2) as INT)
--AND if(nonsub.EmployeeID is null, sub.EmployeeID, nonsub.EmployeeID) = 50125
```